# pyspark interpreter not found in apache zeppelin

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, hortonworks-data-platform, apache-zeppelin

I am having issue with using pyspark in Apache-Zeppelin (version 0.6.0) notebook. Running the following simple code gives me `pyspark interpreter not found` error

```
%pyspark
a = 1+3
```

Running `sc.version` gave me `res2: String = 1.6.0` which is the version of spark installed on my machine. And running `z` return `res0: org.apache.zeppelin.spark.ZeppelinContext = {}`

1. Pyspark works from CLI (using spark 1.6.0 and python 2.6.6)
2. The default python on the machine 2.6.6, while anaconda-python 3.5 is also installed but not set as default python.
3. Based on this [post](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/16436/cants-get-pyspark-interpreter-to-work-on-zeppelin.html) I updated the zeppelin-env.sh file located at `/usr/hdp/current/zeppelin-server/lib/conf` and added Anaconda python 3 path

> ```
> export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/opt/anaconda3/bin/python
> export PYTHONPATH=/opt/anaconda3/bin/python
> ```

After that I have stopped and restarted zeppelin many times using

```
/usr/hdp/current/zeppelin-server/lib/bin/zeppelin-daemon.sh
```

But I can't get the pyspark interpreter to work in zeppelin.

Comment: try %spark.pyspark

Comment: Now I get error message ```spark.pyspark
 interpreter not found```

Comment: I just downloaded 0.6 now and it works for me. sc.version is 1.6.1. there should have some indication in zeppelin/logs/zeppelin-interpreter-spark-*.log

Comment: The exports did the trick for me with this setup, https://github.com/dylanmei/docker-zeppelin/blob/master/examples/local-data-files/docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 2):

To people who found out pyspark not responding, please try to restart your spark interpreter in Zeppelin,it may solve pyspark not responding 
error.